# switch : break without a case

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I have the following `switch` with a `break` without a `case` :

```
char c = 'a';
switch(c) {
    break;
    case 'a' : cout << 'a' << endl;
    break;
    case 'b' : cout << 'b' << endl;
    break;
    default : break;
}
```

Why does this code snippet print `a`? Shoudn't the switch break after encountering the first `break` statement only?

Comment: `switch` and `break` doesn't work like that (as you noticed). Statements not in `case` labels are simply disregarded.

Comment: No, why? In switch you enter the code once appropriate case is encountered. Else default is trigerred. Why would that case-less break be even considered? It should be a warning when case-less code is in switch, tho.

Comment: fwiw, i was expecting that this can be answered by reading https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break, though after reading that one can still believe that your code does what you expect...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first `break` is ignored.

At `switch(c)`, the runtime jumps to `case 'a'` as `c=='a'`. Everything before that is ignored.

This is why `case 'b'` works without printing `'a'`, and this is why variable definitions are frowned upon in `switch` blocks:

```
int n=0;
switch (n)
{
    int k=n;
case 0:
    return k; // UB
}
```

Comment: It seems to be ill-formed, not UB. I get `error: cannot jump from switch statement to this case label` `note: jump bypasses variable initialization`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I _think_ this is UB but all major compilers are nice enough to raise an error; I see no mention of variables having different lifetime in `switch` blocks: http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.switch

Comment: Also, nothing about `switch` here: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup

Comment: Hmm. I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931168/is-jumping-over-a-variable-initialization-ill-formed-or-causes-ub) about it.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a `case` inside a `switch` is (analogous to) a goto label. The head of the `switch` is analogous to the `goto` itself.

### Consequences

- `break` must in general be used because the "switch-in" is goto-based ie not structured or single point of entry&exit
- Any statement before the first `case` is never reached
- Famous usage [Duffs Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device)

Answer (score 1):

A `switch` is a compact and readable form of what could be a series of ugly `if`s and `goto`s otherwise:

```
char c = 'a';
if(c=='a')goto _a;         // test for "case 'a':"
if(c=='b')goto _b;         // test for "case 'b':"
goto _default;             // unconditional jump to "default:"
goto _break;               // <-- program never goes to this line, the one you are asking about
_a: cout << 'a' << endl;
goto _break;
_b: cout << 'b' << endl;
goto _break;
_default:
goto _break;
_break:
```

Test: https://ideone.com/OgsQuT

Answer (score 0):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch):

> If condition evaluates to the value that is equal to the value of one of constant_expressions, then control is transferred to the statement that is labeled with that constant_expression.
>
> If condition evaluates to the value that doesn't match any of the case: labels, and the default: label is present, control is transferred to the statement labeled with the default: label.

The `switch` works as if there was a `goto` from the condition to the `case`s, hence your `break` is never executed. More generally anything you put there is dead code:

```
switch(1) {
    foo();                // dead code !
    case 1 : cout << '1'; // prints "1"
         break;       // and exits the switch
    case 2 : cout << '2';
         break;
}
```