# Is jumping over a variable initialization ill-formed or does it cause undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, goto, initializer, variable-declaration

Consider this code:

```
void foo()
{
    goto bar;
    int x = 0;
    bar: ;
}
```

GCC and Clang [reject it](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qcfmof), because the jump to `bar:` bypasses variable initialization. MSVC doesn't complain at all (except using `x` after `bar:` causes a warning).

We can do a similar thing with a `switch`:

```
void foo()
{
    switch (0)
    {
        int x = 0;
        case 0: ;
    }
}
```

Now all three compilers [emit errors](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4F3diV).

Are those snippets ill-formed? Or do they cause UB?

I used to think that both were ill-formed, but I can't find the revelant parts of the standard. [[stmt.goto]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.goto) doesn't say anything about this, and neither does [[stmt.select]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.switch).

Comment: Issue would be more trivial if you use `x` after the jump.

Comment: not the standard, but here one can find some information on it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto  in particular: "If transfer of control enters the scope of any automatic variables (e.g. by jumping forward over a declaration statement), the program is ill-formed (cannot be compiled), unless ..."

Comment: Add the `/permissive-` flag to MSVC and it will complain as well. I don't know though whether MSVC's behavior without that flag is well-defined (I would assume so, otherwise why would they allow it?).

Comment: @walnut *"otherwise why would they allow it"* Possibly for backward compatibity, or because they don't care about the standard too much. All major compilers don't conform to the standard under default settings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7334968/4386278

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's ill-formed when the initialization is non-vacuous.

> **[stmt.dcl]**
>
> [3](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.stmt#stmt.dcl-3) It is possible to transfer into a block, but not in a way that
>   bypasses declarations with initialization (including ones in
>   conditions and init-statements). A program that jumps from a point
>   where a variable with automatic storage duration is not in scope to a
>   point where it is in scope is ill-formed unless the variable has
>   vacuous initialization ([basic.life]). In such a case, the variables
>   with vacuous initialization are constructed in the order of their
>   declaration.

The initializer makes the initialization non-vacuous. To contrast, this

```
void foo()
{
    goto bar;
    int x; // no initializer
    bar: ;
}
```

would be well-formed. Though the usual caveats about using `x` with an indeterminate value would apply.

Comment: don't variable declarations have to be the first thing in a scope anyway?

Comment: @Cruncher - C89 required it. C++ never did, and neither does modern C anymore.

Answer (score 4):

From [goto statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto):

> If transfer of control enters the scope of any automatic variables
>   (e.g. by jumping forward over a declaration statement), the program is
>   ill-formed (cannot be compiled), unless all variables whose scope is
>   entered have
>
> 1. scalar types declared without initializers
> 2. class types with trivial default constructors and trivial destructors declared
>      without initializers
> 3. cv-qualified versions of one of the above
> 4. arrays of one of the above